# VS Resets IIS Folder Permissions On Publish

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, webserver, iis-7.5, publish

After I set a user to have `full permissions` on my website on IIS 7.5, then I publish (using VS 2010) to find that the permissions for that user have been reset to `read` only.

I publish quite often so any way around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this that keeps the permissions intact :

1. Share the web server `www` folder
2. Publish to that folder using `"File System"` publish option.

However you must publish at least once using the normal deploy method, so that the correct account is created on the webserver.